# After completion of one azure pipeline, only one of two pipelines is triggered

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-triggers

We have three pipelines:

- BUILD
- DEPLOY
- DEPLOY2

After completion of BUILD, we want to start DEPLOY and DEPLOY2 automatically and in parallel.

But right now only DEPLOY starts and DEPLOY2 is not triggered. Both are same configured:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: 'build'
    source: 'BUILD'
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - refs/heads/*
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: I can reproduce your situation and solve it, see my answer and check whether it can solve your issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

The definition of your resource trigger should be correct. I can reproduce your situation with the same YAML definition as yours. And I can also solve the situation.

***1, check whether the pipeline DEPLOY2 still enable(Also make sure the YAML is using correct.):***

[image]

[image]

***2, check whether the resource trigger definition is in the default branch of the pipeline DEPLOY2.***

Please notice that only default branch of the pipeline will be able to get the build pipeline completed information.

For example, on my side:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You have two ways in this situation.

> Change the resource trigger to the correct definition.

> Change the branch which has correct resource trigger to the default
> branch.

How to change the default branch of the pipeline:

[image]

[image]